# Unknown USB device on Windows CE

Tags: usb, windows-ce

We have a project, where we use really old project specific Windows CE 5.0 devices in a kiosk application. We are trying to replace the USB connected Lexmark T640 printer with a new USB printer (Kyocera P3055dn). The printer works, but Windows CE complains about an unknown USB device (in the moddle of the screen). How do I prevent this message?

Comment: Wrong site. You're looking for [su] instead. This site is for programming related questions, not general computer or OS support. More information is available in the [help]. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Windows CE 6.0 introduced a registry setting to suppress this message:

```
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Drivers\USB\LoadClients]
    "DoNotPromptUser"=dword:1
```

This won't work on Windows CE 5.0 however, unless there's a recent QFE that I'm unaware of.

If you are able to modify the OS image, then one solution is to clone the USB sources and disable the message.

Another way to avoid the message (which doesn't require changing the OS image) is to create a USB driver that accepts the unknown device, and does nothing with it. You could choose to match the USB VID/PID combination specifically, or you could make the driver match any unknown device.